# Jar file not found exception when running map reduce job when copying data from hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When I tried to execute the following command to copy data from hbase to another cluster in a hbase client environment. The command I ran is:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --peer.adr=[destination zk]:/hbase  [source table name]
```

I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does
>   not exist:
>   hdfs://servername:8020/opt/hbase-1.2.10/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)

The `/opt/hbase-1.2.10/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar` is on my local path but it does not exist in the hdfs. It seems the CopyTable util is submitting a mapreduce job without the dependency jars. I read a few articles and it seems the only solution is to upload the jar lib to hdfs with the same path. This is really an ugly solution.

Please kindly advise. Thanks!